# Non-example of 1-1 function that satisfies $F(a\cdot b) = F(a) + F(b)$

Tags: group-theory

[image]

For part (b), my argument is that $F(a) = F(1a) = F(1) + F(a)$. Hence $F(1) = 0$. But also $0 = F(1) = F(-1^2) = F(-1) + F(-1) = 2 \times F(-1)$. Hence $F(-1) = 0$. So $F(1) = F(-1) = 0$, and so $F$ is not 1-1.

Which function would be an example for part (b)?

Comment: $F(a) = \ln |a|$?

Answer (score 1):

A typical example: $F(x)=c\log |x|$, where $c\in\mathbb R$. Using the Axiom of Choice one can construct discontinuous such $F$.

$$
2F(-a)=F\big((-a)\cdot(-a)\big)=F(a\cdot a)=2F(a),
$$
and thus $F$ is not one-to-one.